# Непонятная функция JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как тут происходит отправка запроса, ведь такого нету его...

```
let getContact = (message) => {

    var user = message.owner_id,
sort_by = 'default',
limit = message.data.limit+''.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),
offset = message.data.offset+''.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),
arr = [];

arr.push(user.toString());
arr.push(sort_by);
arr.push(limit);
arr.push(offset);

return database.db.any("SELECT * FROM get_user_channels($1, $2, $3, $4)", arr)
        .then(data => {
            return data;
})
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('ERROR:', error);
return {
                status: "ERROR",
reason: "Вернуть контакты не удалось"
};
})
        .finally(() => {
            // database.pgp.end();
});
};

export default  getContact;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`database.db.any` И есть отправка запроса. Нам вернётся промис который при успешном выполнении возвращает `data`.